# beforeUpdate Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Hello I´m using this hook to encrypt the passwords on save

```
Account.beforeUpdate((account, options) => {
    return bcrypt
        .hash(account.password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10))
        .then(hash => {
            account.password = hash;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            throw new Error();
        });
});
```

the problem is that sometimes I update or example the Account name and not the password.
how can I restrict this hook to execute if there´s no password to encrypt?

I found that account.changed("password") will tell me if the password changed or not. now my question is where to put it.

thank you.

Comment: check if there is account.password then execute

Comment: `if(account.password ){     }`